# Finding the same second elements in nested lists - recursive function

Tags: python, list, recursion, python-3.4, nested-lists

I have nested lists looks like this;

```
[['CELTIC AMBASSASDOR', 'Warrenpoint'],['HAV SNAPPER', 'Silloth'],['BONAY', 'Antwerp'],['NINA', 'Antwerp'],['FRI SKIEN', 'Warrenpoint']]
```

and goes on. How can I find the lists that have same second elements, for example

```
['CELTIC AMBASSASDOR', 'Warrenpoint']
['FRI SKIEN', 'Warrenpoint']

['BONAY', 'Antwerp']
['NINA', 'Antwerp']
```

The list is too long (I'm reading it from a .csv file) and I can't determine to search which thing exactly (eg: I can't search for 'Antwerp' to find all Antwerps because I don't know all of the texts in csv file), so I thought I need a recursive function that will search until find the all nested lists seperated by second items. Couldn't figure out how to make the recursive function, if anyone has a better solution, much appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a job for a Collection or a groupby, based on the second element of each list member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use recursion here. Create a dictionary with a key of the second element and values of the whole sublist, then create a result that only includes the matches you're interested in:

```
import collections
l = [['CELTIC AMBASSASDOR', 'Warrenpoint'],['HAV SNAPPER', 'Silloth'],['BONAY', 'Antwerp'],['NINA', 'Antwerp'],['FRI SKIEN', 'Warrenpoint']]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in l:
    d[item[1]].append(item)

result = dict(item for item in d.items() if len(d[item[0]]) > 1)
```

Result:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
{'Antwerp': [['BONAY', 'Antwerp'], ['NINA', 'Antwerp']],
 'Warrenpoint': [['CELTIC AMBASSASDOR', 'Warrenpoint'],
                 ['FRI SKIEN', 'Warrenpoint']]}
```

Comment: Wow. Our answers are almost exactly the same.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Odd how that happens. :P I think yours includes a false positive entry `Silloth': [['HAV SNAPPER', 'Silloth']]`, though.

Comment: Sure, I didn't bother to filter. Yours is more complete. I bow out

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, Is `l` stands for the big list that have nested lists? If it is, what `list` stands for in `d = collections.defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: That's a special kind of dictionary that, if a certain key isn't found, calls the passed argument (`list` in this case) to create an entry with the desired key and the default value. See the documentation for `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(lambda x:x[1] in set(filter(lambda x:zip(*l)[1].count(x)==2,zip(*l)[1])),l)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be more useful as an answer if you added an explanation why this works.